# Get ID of a dynamic control inside gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview control, say, 'grd'. Inside it, I have a template field

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<input id="chkSelectRow" type="checkbox" runat="server" name="chkSelectRow" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

if I bind 5 rows in the grid then there will be 5 check boxes. If I have only 2 rows then there will be 2 check boxes. My question is How can I get the id of each check boxe with javascript from an outside event, say, a button click

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for :

I have written the Jquery code block which will find your checkboxes form `grd` and display it in alert(). you can change code as per your requirement.

HTML for Button :

```
 <input type="button" value="save" onclick="test();" />
```

Jquery:

```
 function test() {

            $('input[type="checkbox"][id*="chkSelectRow"]').each(function () {
                alert($(this).attr('id') + ' : ' + $(this).attr('checked'));
            });
        }
```